# MVC form submit executes action from another Partial View

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, form-submit, partial-views

I am working with `MVC 5`. I have a `View` filled with two `Partial view`. One is the `Header` and the other is the `Body`.

I have this in my header.schtml

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home"))
{
    <div class="DvBotonLogM" >
        <input type="submit" value="Logi IN" title="Log" class="btn2 btn-primary AlinearBoton" />
    </div>
 }
```

And I have this in my `Body.cshtml`

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Create", "Users")" id="formCreate" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="dvUploadCaptcha">
        <div class="dvRegistroAct">
            <input type="submit" value="Grabar" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I sumbit `formCreate` I do it via `Jquery`.

```
$('formCreate').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        var formdata = new FormData($(this).get(0));
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                if (!validarTerms())
                    return false;
            },
            success: function (result) {
                processResponse(result);
            },
            complete: function () {

            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

The problem I have is when I submit Header View, it calls Body submit.

How can I prevent doing this, and just call `Sumbit` action from Header View?

Comment: You're using `$('formCreate')` which is not a valid selector, so you're either *actually* using `$("form")` *or* `$("#formCreate")`.  If it's #formCreate, it should be obvious why formCreate is being submitted.  If it's just "form" then it's likely the way you're triggering the "submit" - how exactly are you attempting to submit the header form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add your form in a container

```
<div class="myContainer">

 <form action="@Url.Action("Create", "Users")" id="formCreate" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="dvUploadCaptcha">
                    <div class="dvRegistroAct">
                        <input type="submit" value="Grabar" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </div>
 </form>

</div>
```

and in the script:

```
 $('.myContainer #formCreate').submit(function (event) {

            });
```

Do the same for the other form and perhaps make the script code into a function.